# How to use DataTables jQuery object with ZendX_jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables, zendx

I am trying to use ZendX_jQuery and Datatables for a project. In my layout file I have:

```
  if($this->jQuery()->isEnabled()){
   $this->jQuery()->setLocalPath('/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js')
    ->setUiLocalPath('/js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js')
    ->addStylesheet('/css/smoothness/custom.css')
    ->addJavascriptFile('/js/jquery.dataTables.js');
   echo $this->jQuery();
  }
```

Whenever I have object being rendered that use the ZendX helper, the datatables object renders fine. However, if I dont have an object then the table wont render.

Examples:

Datatables working because of datepicker:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/smoothness/custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Datatables broken because no datepicker:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/smoothness/custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

The obvious difference here is that without other jQuery objects, ZendX won't place the jQuery UI file in the header. Is there a way to force it to do so? I dont like having to declare the UI script file twice to make sure every page gets it.

Thanks,

Joe Chin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable it yourself, which is otherwise done internally.

> To access the javascript we have to
>   utilize the jQuery() functionality.
>   Both helpers already activated their
>   dependencies that is they have called
>   **jQuery()->enable()** and
>   **jQuery()->uiEnable()** [...]

[Source](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.view.html#zendx.jquery.view.jquery)

That's referring to the view helper for jQuery, so it's `$this->view->jQuery()->enable()` within a controllers action or `$this->jQuery()->enable()` within a view.